# Flux from (All buckets) in Influxdb 2

Tags: flux, influxdb-2

I have a dynamic amount of buckets that i want to list, i only want to list the buckets that contain a specific value from a field.

So a more specific explanation here:

I have x amount of bucket, each bucket have a field called software, i want to list only the buckets containing a certain value in software.

Example:

```
if bucket == (
    <bucket>
        <Measurement>
            <Field> == "Software"
                <_value> == "test" ) {
    list.append(bucket)
else {
    continue
}
```

I only need the names of the buckets to show them in a list to show the graphs with data from that system.

It's used in a dashboard variable where i now use:

```
buckets()
```

And the chosen system is in the queries in the dashboards panels.

The thought is that each dashboard is one software so we have all the systems/buckets with that software to choose from in the list.

A system can change software and some other factors make me want to have the system as the bucket instead of the software.

I have tried everything i can find on google and youtube but none give the answer to how to query a dynamic amount of buckets/all buckets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way if i use the regex either in the query with the regexp package

```
import "regexp"

// ending with abc
re = regexp.compile(v: ".*abc")

data = from(bucket: "example-bucket")
    |> range(start: -1h)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => regexp.matchRegexpString(r: re, v: r._measurement))
```

Or just setting a regex in Grafana on the dashboards variable regex box